# how to upload an image of product in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, media

I would like to upload an image of product in drupal commerce programmatically while creating a product, Here is my code for create product, but drupal return error said

```
Call to a member function set() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\sites\all\modules\api\mymodule.inc
```

any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

mymodule.inc

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', commerce_product_new('product'));
$properties = entity_get_property_info('commerce_product');

$wrapper->title = $title;
$wrapper->sku = $sku;
$wrapper->commerce_price->amount = $price;    // Price in minors units 500 = 5$
$wrapper->commerce_price->currency_code = 'MMK';
$wrapper->cmp_store = 2;
//$wrapper->field_category = 137;
$wrapper->field_product_color = 106;

$file_path = file_save_data(file_get_contents('C:\\Users\\ASUSS\\Desktop\\Nexus_5_(1).jpg'), 'public://products/Nexus_5_(2).jpg');
$wrapper->field_product_image->file->set($file_path);

try{
    $wrapper->save();
    $result = "success!" ;
}catch(Exception $ex){
    $result = "not success! -> ". $ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the way, field_product_image can only accept array value. Here is my code,

```
function commerce_services_product_create($data, $flatten_fields) {
    $status =1;
    $commerce_price = array();

    $sku = $data['sku'];
    $title = $data['title'];
    $type = $data['type'];
    $commerce_price = $data['commerce_price'];
    $price = $commerce_price['amount'];

    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product',  commerce_product_new('product'));
    $properties = entity_get_property_info('commerce_product');

    $wrapper->title = $title;
    $wrapper->sku = $sku;
    $wrapper->commerce_price->amount = $price;    // Price in minors units 500 = 5$
    $wrapper->commerce_price->currency_code = 'MMK';
    $wrapper->cmp_store = 2;
    $wrapper->field_product_color = 106;

    $file = file_save_data(file_get_contents('C:\\Users\\ASUSS\\Desktop\\Nexus_5_(1).jpg'), 'public://products/Nexus_5_(2).jpg');
    $image_val = array(
        array(
            'fid' => $file->fid,
            'title' => $file->filename,
            'filename' => $file->filename,
            'filepath' => $file->filepath,
            'filesize' => $file->filesize
        ),
    );

    $wrapper->field_product_image = $image_val;

    try{
        $wrapper->save();
        $result = "success!" ;
    }catch(Exception $ex){
        $result = "not success! -> ". $ex;
    }

    $reply= (array('status' => $status,'result' => $result) );
    return $reply;
}
```

Thanks,